# SQL query - simple query so why isn't it updating?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my new code to update the ' lastactive ' column for the respective user but it still isn't updating the lastactive. The datatype for lastactive is **Time** so it should slot right in, what am I doing wrong?

```
$userID  = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$dbusername' AND password = '$dbpassword' ");
mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET lastactivity = ".time()." WHERE ID = ".$userID);M
```

Comment: What is `$userID` filled with and does it exist in your table?

Comment: That is not an SQL query -- that is PHP code that creates an SQL query by text interpolation.  To debug do two things: display the query before you send it to the database, and execute the query *as displayed* (not as you think it would be constructed) and see what the database says.  I think you will find the query you are sending is not exactly the query you think you are sending.

Comment: `$userID` is an integer. So far I have one entry so it is just 1. Yes I have a column for ID.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` returns FALSE on error, or a result object on success.

You must call the `fetch_all` or `fetch_assoc` methods of it, and then pick your single value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your `$userID` hasn't been fetched from the `mysqli_query` call. Bear in mind that the [return type for queries](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) is

> FALSE on failure. For successful *SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE* or *EXPLAIN* queries `mysqli_query()` will return a [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return TRUE.

To get the ID out of the result, you need to fetch the data with [fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). (Note that mysql_fetch_array is deprecated and should not be used.)

```
if( $result  = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$dbusername' AND password = '$dbpassword' ")) {

     // Fetch the row
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     // Update the time
     $success = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET lastactivity = '".time()."' WHERE ID = '".$row['id']."' ");

     // Report success of second query
     if( $success) {
         echo 'Success';
     } else {
         echo 'Failed to update lastactivity for user ID ' . $row['id'];
     }

} else {
    // Report failure of first query
    echo 'User ID select query failed.';
}
```